# Is there a way to display/list all behat scenario with specific tag?

Tags: symfony, behat

I have Symfony2 project with Behat used for BDD tests.

Most of tests are tagged, like:

```
  @database @user_management @admin
  Scenario: Attempt .....
  ....
  ....

  @product @admin
  Scenario: Login ....
  ....
  ....
```

I would like to be able to list all scenerios tagged with specific tag, before running entire test suite. Is it possible?
I mean I can write small script which analyzes all features files, but I hope there is some behat magic switch/flag, already implemented, but not documented, which does what I need.

Comment: Do you mean `behat --tags '@admin,@product'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not personally aware of a built-in way, partly because it depends on what you expect as an output.

One way to get something similar would be to dry-run the scenarios, with the full items being displayed, and then grep for 'scenario', to get the name/summary:

```
behat --format=pretty --tags '@domains' --dry-run | grep -i scenario
```

Comment: The fact that behat doesn't have this feature is shocking.
If you have test specifications in code, then you probably want some way to look at what features/scenarios you have with a specified tag, for example.